# Lighting glb models in Three JS with minimal shadows

Tags: javascript, three.js, lighting, gltf

Not sure if I worded my title right but I'm getting my feet wet with three JS. Right now I have a simple glb model that I would like to import into my scene, but I can't get the lighting right. The image below is what I want to accomplish.

[image]

But when I import my glb into my scene and add some lighting this is what it looks like
[image]

The model is quite dark and I can't get it to light up ideally. I've tried adding ambient lights top-down, point lights as a child to the camera instance, hemisphere lights, etc. but I just can't get it to look right. Below is the code for the current lighting; I'm trying to achieve the look by using point lights atm.

```
var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 10 );
light.position.z = 10
camera.add(light)
var light2 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 10 );
light2.position.set(0, -20, 30)
scene.add(light2)
```

If anyone could give me some insights as to what is the proper way to achieve what I am desiring that will be great.

Answer (score 3):

So I did some digging in, and it turns out that Blender includes this thing called an environment map

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/exporting-blender-scene-lighting-issues/11887/8

So I had to recreate the environment in my scene as well.

After importing RoomEnvironment like so:

`import { RoomEnvironment } from 'three/examples/jsm/environments/RoomEnvironment';`

I created the room environment:

```
const environment = new RoomEnvironment();
const pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator( renderer );
scene.environment = pmremGenerator.fromScene( environment ).texture;
```

Then I added the following attributes to my scene object:

```
renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
renderer.toneMappingExposure = 1.2;
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
```

After that, it lights up just as fine! I honestly don't really know what these toneMapping stuff do at the moment, but for now this solves my problem.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  There are some additional source files online that show glTF files being loaded with a full environment, for example [gltf-test](https://github.com/cx20/gltf-test/blob/master/examples/threejs/index.js), [gltf-vscode](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/gltf-vscode/blob/master/pages/threeView.js), and of course [Don's glTF Viewer](https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer).

Comment: @emackey Did not know this. Thanks for sharing :)